# Angularjs material dialog not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an Array of items which I want to output in a dialog. I do not get an error, but it is not working either.

```
    $scope.showDialog = function (ev) {
      $mdDialog.alert({
        controller: 'DialogController',
        controllerAs: 'DiaCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'softwareused.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        locals: {
          items: cvLibsUsed
        }
  });
};
```

This should open an alert dialog as pointed out [here](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1413#issuecomment-73248708)
When I tried the [demo code](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog) I got the error, that "alert" is not defined.

The template looks like this:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Software used">
<md-dialog-content>
    <h2>Software used</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="cur in locals.items"><a ng-href="{{cur.url}}">{{cur.desc}}</a> - (<a
                ng-href="{{cur.licenceUrl}}">{{cur.licence}}</a>
            )
        </li>
    </ul>
</md-dialog-content>
<md-dialog-actions layout="row">
    <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="close()" aria-label="Close dialog" md-autofocus>
        Close
    </md-button>
</md-dialog-actions>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? No AngularJS error and no dialog.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **`$mdDialog.show`** Instead of **`$mdDialog.alert`**

```
 $scope.showDialog = function (ev) {
      $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'DialogController',
        controllerAs: 'DiaCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'softwareused.tmpl.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        locals: {
          items: cvLibsUsed
        }
  });
```

Here is a sample [mdDialog](http://plnkr.co/edit/7SMgJS?p=preview)

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I could trace the invocation of the $mdDialog.show() method call within the debugger, and no errors appeared in the console, yet no dialog appeared. It proved to be a CSS issue, where the template I was using contained elements with a z-index higher than that used by the components making up the MD dialog, effectively obscuring the dialog message.

The following CSS rule updates were one approach to solving the problem (on the basis that I did not want to touch the template itself):

```
.md-scroll-mask { z-index: 2000; }
md-backdrop.md-dialog-backdrop { z-index: 2019; }
.md-dialog-container {  z-index: 2020; }
```

Comment: We prefer posts without voting advice, mainly because most readers don't vote. In any case, I don't think people pay any attention to such messages `:-)`.

Comment: If you say so, but the only reason I put the note in is because I HAVE seen people downvoted for exactly this reason.

Comment: Yes, and the converse is true as well: some people downvote because someone told them not to `:-D`. This answer looks helpful anyway. My advice is not to worry about the odd DV, they are only -2, and if you keep active you'll gain much more than you lose.